# Attach Custom Information to Commerce Order Model

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

I have shipping methods that will require additional information from the user. For example, a local delivery `shipping method` which requires the user to include a timeframe for delivery (say, Thursday @ 3pm.)

I thought I'd go about it doing something like this:

---

1. On select shipping page during checkout, user selects the delivery date/time (based on what is available.)
2. User selects date, then submits form.
3. **That date is attached somewhere to the order model.**
4. The shipping method rules will validate the chosen date.
5. Include this additional information (selected delivery date) in saved order on checkout completion.

---

Is there a way to do this? Basically, I need to attach additional information for this shipping method (and another similar one.) I've looked through the [order model docs](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model) but can't find a field I could add ***custom*** data to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a custom plain text field to your orders, say `test`.

Then, when calling `updateCart`, you can add data in to this custom field using a form with an input named like this:

```
  <input name="fields[test]" type="text"> etc...
```

This data will then get saved with the order.  This same approach can basically be applied to any field/type.

To actually validate the data, you'll need to look to making a plugin, most likely listening to onBeforeSaveOrder to check the vailidity of the data.  If valid, great, if not, set `perfomAction` to false and return an error on the Order model.

See https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onbeforesaveorder

Comment: I've been trying this but the custom field/val never gets saved to the order model after calling updateCart. Are you saying that I would look for the form's custom field->value through the onbeforesaveorder event and do everything from there? I was hoping there'd simply be a way to just add a new field/value to the order model without any logic from listening to an event.

Comment: You only need the plugin for validation. The field data should save with any update of the cart. Maybe post your input and output code?